# Locker Service callback.call failing when passing object for event listener

Tags: locker-service

We have https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable working in our Lightning Components, however when we enable Locker Service we see an exception in Aura core code.

Uncaught TypeError: callback.call is not a function throws at https://win16f1l-dev-ed--sum16fw1.na30.visual.force.com/auraFW/javascript/h_soHR8Rt2_c3cVcuaSlUA/aura_proddebug.js:17830:20

It seems like the error happens when do

```
var obj = {
handleEvent: function() {
    alert(this.dude);
},
   dude: "holla"
};

element.addEventListener("click", obj, false);
```

Locker seems to have an issue calling the **handleEvent** method when you pass an object to the event listener.

Is this a known issue or is it explicitly blocked by Locker Service?

Comment: That is correct - currently Locker only supports the function datatype for the callback argument. This is the first time this has been reported, asked for, etc - do you have a support case opened on this or an idea on IdeaExchange?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `$A.getCallback(function callback)` as it ensures that the framework rerenders the modified component and processes any enqueued actions

```
element.addEventListener("click", $A.getCallback(handleEventFunction), false);
```

Comment: $A.getCallback requires to me provide a function but if I want to pass the object and have JS call the handleEvent method automatically I cannot do that with $A.getCallback. The reason this is important is because we can pass the object and all of the references to the handleEvent method.

Comment: can't you do something like that ?
$A.getCallback(function(){ 
//do whatever you need with the variable obj
})

Answer (score -1):

@kevan, Thanks for the answer. I was able to do the following:

```
if (this.nativeDraggable) {
        var self = this;
        _on(el, 'dragover', $A.getCallback(function(e){
            handleEventManually(e,self);
        }));
        _on(el, 'dragenter', $A.getCallback(function(e){
            handleEventManually(e,self);
        }));
    }
```

It seems like Locker Service does not allow the JS functionality that will auto call the **handleEvent** method when you pass an object as the callback.  You have to use $A.getCallback and then create a manual event method to make sure everything is handled correctly.